# Correlation function over analytic function

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have a table looks like

```
TDate         Name     Value     
20110101     xxx      1.2
20110102     xxx      1.3
...
20110101     yyy      3.4
20110101     yyy      32.1
```

I want to calculate the the correlation of value between each name (say between xxx and yyy). Here is my code:

```
Create table corrDEC as
Select distinct a.name ASymbol,b.name BSymbol, 
corr(a.value,b.value) over (partition by a.name,b.name)  Correlation
From logprofitDEC a, logprofitDEC b
where a.name<>b.name
Order by 1,2,3 desc;
```

Do I have to add

```
where To_date(a.Tdate,'YYYYMMDD')=To_date(b.Tdate,'YYYYMMDD')
```

in the where clause please?

How to improve my efficiency by fix where clause please?

Comment: Well, `corr` is symmetric, so you only need `where a.name < b.name`.

Comment: Thanks Jack, I fix that already.

Comment: I'm not seeing a huge difference in the five times you've asked about this.

Comment: Hello Alex, Thanks for reply. I just can't figure out the problem here, the code can runs but it exceed the disk limit of Oracle XE, I am trying to simply the it but don't know how. Would you be so kind to give me some advise?

Answer (score 0):

If you want the correlation between the x's and y's and they each have a date associated with them, then you want something like:

```
select corr(x, y)
from (select tdate, max(case when name = 'xxx' then value end) as x
             max(case when name = 'yyy' then value end) as y
      from logprofitDEC
      group by tdate
     ) t;
```

Although you can express this as an analytic function, I do not see the advantage in doing so.

Comment: Thanks gordon for your kindly reply. There is one more problem. If my table is huge with ~5000 name, how to fix the code you gave to solve it please?

Comment: @user4441082 . . . That is a different question.  I think you will have to write a PL/SQL loop to handle the 12.5 million combinations of name pairs.

Comment: Thanks for your patience, I am stuck on this problem for two days. Don't know how to fix it...

Comment: @user4441082 . . . I would suggest that you ask another question, better describing what you are trying to do with sample data and a better discussion of what the data looks like.